# Testing for session variables using Rack::Test using RSpec

Tags: ruby, session, rspec, rack, rack-test

Given the code

```
env "rack.session", {:var => 'value'}
```

I can set a session variable in rack-test. However, how can I (using rack-test) test for said session variable in RSpec? Hypothetically, for example:

```
expect(env['rack.session'][:var]).to eq('value')
```

I can't seem to find any documentation for reading Rack environment variables, only writing them.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the [session method](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request/Helpers#session-instance_method) on the last request:

```
last_request.session
```

This will give you the session hash.
A Sample:

```
it 'allows to access the session' do                                                                                                                                          
  get '/'                                                                                                                                                                     
  session = last_request.session                                                                                                                                              
  expect(session).to be_a Hash                                                                                                                                                
  expect(session[:var]).to eq 'value'                                                                                                                                         
end
```

I've tested with rack v1.6.5 and rack-test v0.6.3 but it should work as well with rack version 2.